# How do you avoid circular imports in Python?

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

How do you manage a situation when your project consists of two and more files and you end up with a need to import everything everywhere?

```
--main.py
---some-stuff.py
---some-stuff2.py
```

I can't go for circular dependency, but the structure of the program demands it.
Is there a way to manage the situation apart from doing all the works in one file, including all the code?

Comment: The general answer is "make the parts not need to know so much about each other". How you do that in any specific case may vary. Perhaps there's a way to divide the work in a way that makes the sub-tasks more self-contained. Perhaps you really can just pass the necessary information as arguments, and you just haven't realized how to do it. Perhaps object-oriented programming would allow you to manage the state of your program better. It's hard to tell.

Comment: It would help if you provided some concrete examples.

Comment: It sounds like you have split up your code in a bad way.  I'd be tempted to start by copying everything into main.py and then thinking again about how to move stuff out of there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Standard Answer**

Pass the bits of data as arguments to the functions you call in `some-stuff.py`.

If your `some-stuff.py` defines a function `foo` which needs some field `bar` that is defined in `main`, change the definition of `foo` to `foo(bar, <other args>)`, and when your script inside `main.py` calls `foo`, it can call it as  `foo(bar, <other args>)`.

**Addressing Your Limitation**

You mention that it is "Not achievable by passing arguments to call of function in some-stuff, as the variables might not have their values by then".

If you have functions inside `some-stuff` that requires variables from `main` before they have been given values, then you should break up the function into multiple functions so that that functionality is not invoked until the value it requires is available. That is likely to improve the modularity of your code anyways.